# Android - Get notified when near BLE device

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon, google-awareness

I need my app to get notified when it is in range of a specific BLE device. Once in range, I want to connect to the device and send data to it.

**Approach 1:**
Periodic BLE scans at some interval (i.e. every 30 seconds). However, this would not be good for battery. I can improve this a bit by only scanning when the device location is near the location of the BLE device (via Android Geofence APIs). But still, not great for battery.

**Approach 2:**
Use Android Awareness API. This seems like a great candidate. However, it seems you are forced to register your BLE device with Google as a BLE beacon. Does anyone know if this is an absolute requirement? I do not want to register it with Google.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into the Android [Altbeacon](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library) library. It can do what you need with battery saving features.

Regarding approach 1, sample code from the library below.

```java
public class MonitoringActivity extends Activity implements BeaconConsumer {
    protected static final String TAG = "MonitoringActivity";
    private BeaconManager beaconManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ranging);
                beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
        // To detect proprietary beacons, you must add a line like below corresponding to your beacon
        // type.  Do a web search for "setBeaconLayout" to get the proper expression.
        // beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
        //        setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));
        beaconManager.bind(this);
    }
    @Override 
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        beaconManager.unbind(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
        beaconManager.removeAllMonitorNotifiers();
        beaconManager.addMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
            Log.i(TAG, "I just saw an beacon for the first time!");        
        }

        @Override
        public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
            Log.i(TAG, "I no longer see an beacon");
        }

        @Override
            public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {
            Log.i(TAG, "I have just switched from seeing/not seeing beacons: "+state);        
            }
        });

        try {
            beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myMonitoringUniqueId", null, null, null));
        } catch (RemoteException e) {    }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#connectGatt(android.content.Context,%20boolean,%20android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback,%20int,%20int) with autoConnect=true? The duty cycle of the radio is like 4% so it hardly consumes any battery.